# 2D Pattern Searching

Tags: c#, algorithm, design-patterns

What would be a good algorithm for searching through 2D arrays of data and creating borders around data of the same sort? The data would be random so there wouldn't be any prior knowledge of the data available, other than that it'd contain numeric values.

Otherwise are there any good articles/books on the subject?

**Edit**

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

And the same for the two's

Comment: Maybe you're looking to draw a convex hull around your data? There are many algorithms out there for that (see i.e. Wikipedia).

Comment: sounds like you want linq.groupby

Comment: Could you provide a small 2d array example? Otherwise, there are numerous algorithms which could fit.

Comment: What if there's a load of `1` values not contiguous with the other `1` values? Does that count as two separate regions, or would you want a single region around them all?

Comment: Yes it would count as a separate region

Comment: Ok, now what exactly should your border do? Do you just want to draw it, like in the example, or use it to for example say that '2' belongs to region 'B' or something like that (classification problem) or do you just want to guess from a coordinate what class it belongs to ...

Comment: I want to create a data structure that creates the boundary path that can then be written to a file format like GDS II

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill for each point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breadth First Search could help you here.First construct the graph **G** as follows:

Graph **G** has edge **(u,v)** is and only if value of u-th cell=value of v-th cell.

Then carrying out BFS gives nice pieces of the graph that you can conveniently mark as visited using the value of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex problem which I think is equivalent to finding the concave hull of a set of points.

You would first have to define an equality operation for the data points so that you can determine the set of "same sort" data points.

Having identified a set of points in that way, you then need to find the concave hull for that set of points.

(I'm assuming you want the concave hull and not the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)).

Finding the concave hull is a non-trivial task.

See here for details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/concave-hull-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions

If it's actually the convex hull you want, see here for an implementation in C#:

http://miconvexhull.codeplex.com/

Comment: This is a very good suggestion indeed. After the edit of the original post, it seems like finding the concave hull is indeed what is necessary here. However, if, like the picture suggests, the input is actually just a 2D array, it is probably simpler than that and a (non-geometric) search algorithm will probably do.

Comment: In the definition of a concave hull, you'll need to define some type of restriction on your polygon (otherwise, the minimal area of 0 is achieved by lines connecting each of your points).

Answer (score 0):

A naive solution (which will work fine for small data sets) is to define a comparison operator that takes two arguments and returns true if they are equal and false otherwise and then simply compare all pairs of adjacent values (both horizontally and vertically) and drawing a border if the comparison returns false.

Comment: Unfortunately this is for rather large data sets.

Comment: How large? How often do you need to do this calculation? Even for milions of data points this will be very fast, so unless you have billions of them and need to do this in real-time this could be okay.